# Space as a token its impact on evaluation of binary or unary operator

Tags: c, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error, operators

I being wondering the tokens and how they are evaluated by the compiler, But I never considered space as a essential token for making a statement valid syntactically,

For example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

        int first=1,second=3;
        int res=first+++++second;
        printf("%d \n",res);
        return 0;
}
```

Gives the following error:

> rough3.c:7:17: error: lvalue required as increment operand
>    int res=first+++++second;

But by simply appending a "  " between two postfix (++) and prefix (++)
seems to work fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

        int first=1,second=3;
        int res=first++ + ++second;
        printf("%d \n",res);
        return 0;
}
```

Works fine prints value 5.
I have looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878364/expression-evaluation-in-c-involving-unary-operators) rather then undefined behavior I want to know :
When does compiler decides that spaces between expression are redundant or not?
What happens when we take precedence and associativity together to evaluate these expressions?

Comment: See the ["Maximal Munch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) rule.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  The question was asked earlier this week and closed as a duplicate of other questions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A canonical duplicate does indeed exist. Closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int res=first+++++second;
```

is interpreted as

```
int res = (first++)++ +second;
```

hence the compilation error because `(first++)` is not an l-value.

but

```
int res=first++ + ++second;
```

is interpreted as

```
int res = (first++) + (++second);
```

which is correct.

Comment: don't you like those `++++++++` questions ?

Comment: thanks for the answer :).

Answer (score 4):

According to the C Standard (6.4 Lexical elements)

> 4 If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to
>   a given character, **the next preprocessing token is the longest
>   sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.**
>   There is one exception to this rule: header name preprocessing tokens
>   are recognized only within #include preprocessing directives and in
>   implementation-deﬁned locations within #pragma directives. In such
>   contexts, a sequence of characters that could be either a header name
>   or a string literal is recognized as the former.

Thus for this declaration

```
int res=first+++++second;
```

if the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to
the name `first` then the next longest preprocessing token after the identifier `first` is `++`

```
int res=first++ +++second;
             ^^
```

Then the next longest preprocessing token is again `++`

```
int res=first++ ++ +second;
             ^^ ^^
```

and so on.

So these tokens will be produced

```
int res=first++ ++ + second ;
             ^^ ^^ ^ ^^^^^^ ^
```

According to the C grammar this declaration is considered like

```
int res= (first++)++ + second;
```

And the compiler issues an error because the expression `(first++)` is not an `lvalue`. So  the postfix operator `++` may not be applied to the expression.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation that helps.

Comment: The second case compiles successfully because white space though itself is not a token acts as a separator among tokens hence the evaluation occurs in following order.
`int res=first++ + ++second;`
and compiles without an error. :)